# F# pipe function execution flow

Tags: f#

I am a F# newbie here, the following code is to get all the lines from a csv file which rating > 9.0 then output to a new file.

But I have a hard time figuring out how many for loop does it takes to get the job done, is it all the steps are done in one for loop or 5 for loops as I highlight below?

If it need 5 for loops to get the job done, it should have load the whole file into memory after completing the 2nd loop, but the process only consumes 14M of memory the whole time, less than the csv file.

I know StreamReader will not load the whole file into memory at once, but how the following code execute?

thx in advance...

```
let ratings = @"D:\Download\IMDB\csv\title.ratings.csv"
let rating9 = @"D:\Download\IMDB\csv\rating9.csv"

let readCsv reader =
    Seq.unfold (fun (r:StreamReader) ->         // 1st for loop
        match r.EndOfStream with
        | true -> None
        | false -> Some (r.ReadLine(), r)) reader

let toTuple = fun (s:string) ->
    let ary = s.Split(',')
    (string ary.[0], float ary.[1], int ary.[2])           

using (new StreamReader(ratings)) (fun sr ->
    use sw = new StreamWriter(rating9)
    readCsv sr
    |> Seq.map toTuple                          // 2nd for loop
    |> Seq.filter (fun (_, r, _) -> r > 9.0)    // 3rd for loop
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun (_, r, _) -> r)          // 4th for loop
    |> Seq.iter (fun (t, r, s) ->               // 5th for loop
        sw.WriteLine(sprintf "%s,%.1f,%i" t r s)))
```

Comment: Why not use the CSV type provider? http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

Comment: @KevinAvignon reading csv is just a example here, I am trying to understand the underlying execution logic in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing piece in your understanding is that F#'s `Seq` is ***lazy***. It will not do any more work than needed, and in particular, it will not consume the sequence until it's absolutely necessary to do so. In particular, `Seq.map` and `Seq.filter` do not act like for loops; instead, they act like a transformation pipeline that stacks a new transformation on top of the existing ones. The first piece of your code that will actually run through the entire look is `Seq.sortBy` (because sorting a sequence requires knowing what all its values are, so `Seq.sortBy` must consume the entire sequence to do its job). And by that point, the `Seq.filter` step has already happened, so many lines of the CSV file have been thrown out, and that's why the program consumes less memory than the total size of the original file.

Here's a practical demonstration of `Seq` being lazy, typed into the F# Interactive prompt. Watch this:

```
> let s = seq {1..20} ;;
val s : seq<int>

> let t = s |> Seq.map (fun i -> printfn "Starting with %d" i; i) ;;
val t : seq<int>

> let u = t |> Seq.map (fun i -> i*2) ;;
val u : seq<int>

> let v = u |> Seq.map (fun i -> i - 1) ;;
val v : seq<int>

> let w = v |> Seq.filter (fun i -> i > 10) ;;
val w : seq<int>

> let x = w |> Seq.sortBy id ;;
val x : seq<int>

> let y = x |> Seq.iter (fun i -> printfn "Result: %d" i) ;;
Starting with 1
Starting with 2
Starting with 3
Starting with 4
Starting with 5
Starting with 6
Starting with 7
Starting with 8
Starting with 9
Starting with 10
Starting with 11
Starting with 12
Starting with 13
Starting with 14
Starting with 15
Starting with 16
Starting with 17
Starting with 18
Starting with 19
Starting with 20
Result: 11
Result: 13
Result: 15
Result: 17
Result: 19
Result: 21
Result: 23
Result: 25
Result: 27
Result: 29
Result: 31
Result: 33
Result: 35
Result: 37
Result: 39
val y : unit = ()

> let z = w |> Seq.iter (fun i -> printfn "Result: %d" i) ;;
Starting with 1
Starting with 2
Starting with 3
Starting with 4
Starting with 5
Starting with 6
Result: 11
Starting with 7
Result: 13
Starting with 8
Result: 15
Starting with 9
Result: 17
Starting with 10
Result: 19
Starting with 11
Result: 21
Starting with 12
Result: 23
Starting with 13
Result: 25
Starting with 14
Result: 27
Starting with 15
Result: 29
Starting with 16
Result: 31
Starting with 17
Result: 33
Starting with 18
Result: 35
Starting with 19
Result: 37
Starting with 20
Result: 39
val z : unit = ()
```

Notice how even though `Seq.sortBy` needs to consume the whole list in order to do its jobs, since no part of the `Seq` was being requested when I created sequence `x`, it didn't actually start running through the values. Only sequences `y` and `z`, which used `Seq.iter`, actually triggered running through all the values. (But you can see how, with `y` the `sortBy` step had to run in its entirety before the `iter` step could run, but with `z` where there was no `sortBy` step, each value passed all the way through the transformation pipeline one at a time, and only once each value was completely handled did the next value start getting processed).

Comment: Nice example.  I would probably have forced evaluation with `List.ofSeq` or `Array.ofSeq` or something like that.

Comment: @phoog - That's a good idea as a general rule, but since OP used `Seq.iter` as the final step of his pipeline, I figured I should use the same thing as the final step of mine in this specific example.